# Jhipster Prod build failed

Tags: java, spring, maven, webpack, jhipster

When i try to run command : mvnw -Pprod package -DskipTests -e i get this error :

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn
>   (webpack build prod) on project two-g-hub: Failed to run task at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309) at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194) at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107) at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993) at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345) at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:122)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:50)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run
>   task at
>   com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:100)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>   ... 27 more Caused by:
>   com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.TaskRunnerException:
>   'yarn run webpack:prod' failed. at
>   com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.YarnTaskExecutor.execute(YarnTaskExecutor.java:64)
>   at
>   com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.YarnMojo.execute(YarnMojo.java:65)
>   at
>   com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.mojo.AbstractFrontendMojo.execute(AbstractFrontendMojo.java:94)
>   ... 29 more Caused by:
>   com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutionException:
>   org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an
>   error: 1 (Exit value: 1) at
>   com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.execute(ProcessExecutor.java:82)
>   at
>   com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput(ProcessExecutor.java:64)
>   at
>   com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.YarnExecutor.executeAndRedirectOutput(YarnExecutor.java:28)
>   at
>   com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.YarnTaskExecutor.execute(YarnTaskExecutor.java:58)
>   ... 31 more Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException:
>   Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
>   at
>   com.github.eirslett.maven.plugins.frontend.lib.ProcessExecutor.execute(ProcessExecutor.java:74)
>   ... 34 more

Comment: You did not paste the real error which is above. It's probably a webpack error, here you pasted only the maven stack trace. Which version of JHipster?

Comment: There is no error : http://prntscr.com/kfbzdt
It just doesn't move.

Comment: Are you running Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

try the command :

```
yarn webpack:prod
```

to show the real problem.

Comment: Best thing is that this command is completed : http://prntscr.com/kfbuv6
But when i try mvnw -Pprod package -DskipTests -e i get error again